# Get the number of followers with Flask Sqlalchemy

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I am using Flask with Sqlalchemy, and I have created a Many to Many relationship tables where I want to get the top followed tickers.

```
class Users(UserMixin, db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(250), unique=True, nullable=False)
    password = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=False)
    tickers = db.relationship('Tickers', secondary='list', back_populates='users')

class Tickers(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'tickers'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    symbol = db.Column(db.String(100))
    name = db.Column(db.String(500))
    users = db.relationship('Users', secondary='list', back_populates='tickers')

class list(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'list'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    users_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id'))
    tickers_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('tickers.id'))
```

The following line is used in the view to retrieve all tickers

`tickers = Tickers.query.all()`

The template:

```
{% for ticker in tickers %}
    <li class="list-group-item">{{ ticker.name }}: {{ ticker.users }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

Output:

```
    Apple Inc.: [<Users 1>]
    Microsoft Corporation: [<Users 1>]
    Apple Inc.: [<Users 2>]
    Tesla, Inc.: [<Users 2>]
```

The desired output:

```
    Apple Inc.: 2
    Microsoft Corporation: 1
    Tesla, Inc.: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are querying and printing the users, you are getting a list of the users. associated to the ticker. You can just use jinja2 `length` built-in filter `{{ ticker.users | length }}` to count the amount of users in the list.

If you want to do it on the query side you could try this

```py
tickers = session.execute(
        sa.select(Tickers.name, sa.func.count())
        .select_from(list)
        .where(list.tickers_id == Tickers.id)
        .group_by(Tickers.name)
    ).all()
# tickers is now "[('Apple', 2), ('Microsoft', 1), ('Tesla', 3)]"
```

I'm not sure if there is a way to "optimize" the query, but that's one way to do it.